# SQL Server : parsing a JSON column with irregular values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2016 (v13) installation where I am trying to parse a column with JSON data. The data in the column `RequestData` is in the following format:

```
[
    { "Name": "SourceSystem", "Value": "SSValue" },
    { "Name": "SourceSystemId", "Value": "XYZ" }
]
[
    { "Name": "SourceSystemId", "Value": "SSID" },
    { "Name": "SourceSystem", "Value": "SSVALUE2" }
]
```

What I need to get are the values for the `SourceSystem` element of the JSON object in each row. And here is my Select statement:

```
SELECT TOP 2 
    JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Value') AS SourceSystem 
FROM 
    RequestDetail
```

But, due to the order of the JSON elements in the column's data, the values being returned for the `SourceSystem` column are not correct.

```
SSValue, SSID
```

Please note, I need to be able to parse the JSON elements so that the `SourceSystem` column will have correct values, i.e SSValue and SSValue2.

I have also tried `JSON_Query` using some online examples but no luck so far.

Thank you!

**Edit**
The Question has been modified by someone after I posted, so I am adding this for clarification: Each row of data, as given in the Question, will have several 'Name' elements and those Name elements can be SourceSystem or SourceSystemId. The Question shows data from two rows from the database table's column, but, as you can see, the SourceID and SourceSystemId elements in each row are not in the same order between the first and the second row. I simply need to parse SourceSystem element per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using openjson, to get all the data in columns you can use it as any othe table

```
SELECT
Value
FROM RequestDetail
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(RequestDetail.RequestData)
                 WITH (Name nvarchar(20),
  Value nvarchar(20))
WHERE Name = 'SourceSystem';
```

| Value |
| --- |
| SSValue |
| SSVALUE2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ImdaOy4)

Comment: Thank you. Your's also works. And I know I haven't asked, but can I also get the SourceSystemId column's values in the Select? There will be many such parsing of columns. Thanks!

Comment: you mean some thing like this https://dbfiddle.uk/1L0Tis5N if it ust be dynamic you need PIVOT

Comment: The output in your fiddle looks great! Let me incorporate this in my overall script... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you need `OPENJSON` here, not `JSON_VALUE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'[{"Name":"SourceSystem","Value":"SSValue"},{"Name":"SourceSystemId","Value":"XYZ"}]'),
            (N'[{"Name":"SourceSystemId","Value":"SSID"},{"Name":"SourceSystem","Value":"SSVALUE2"}]'))V(YourJSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.YourJSON)
                 WITH (Value nvarchar(20));
```

Comment: Thank you. So I guess I should replace the hard-coded JSON with my column name and give it a try...

Comment: Yes, you would reference your table, rather than a `VALUES` table construct, @IrfanClemson .

Comment: I think if you could, please, replace with the table name in your Answer? I am trying though. Thanks.

Comment: I will need to parse several JSON elements and so the 'AS' in the Select statement is important. Thanks.

Comment: I have run your code with even the hard-coded values but result is not the expected one. Each row of data, as given in the Question, will have several 'Name' elements and those Name elements can be SourceSystem or SourceSystemId. The Question shows two data from two rows but, as you can see, they are not in the same order between the first and the second row. I simply need to parse SourceSystem element per row. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use JSON_VALUE, just select the correct (needed) values:

```sql
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Value') AS SourceSystem
FROM RequestDetail

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[1].Value') AS SourceSystem
FROM RequestDetail
```

output:

| SourceSystem |
| --- |
| SSValue |
| SSID |
| XYZ |
| SSVALUE2 |

When you only need values from "SourceSystem", you can always do:

```sql
SELECT SourceSystem
FROM (
   SELECT 
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Name') AS Name,
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Value') AS SourceSystem
   FROM RequestDetail

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Name') AS Name,
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[1].Value') AS SourceSystem
   FROM RequestDetail )x
WHERE Name='SourceSystem';
```

output:

| SourceSystem |
| --- |
| SSValue |
| XYZ |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/5GIsX4GD)

EDIT:

```sql
SELECT 
    x,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Name='SourceSystem' THEN SourceSystem END) as SourceSystem,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Name='SourceSystemId' THEN SourceSystem END) as SourceSystemId
FROM (
   SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RequestData) as x,
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Name') AS Name,
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[0].Value') AS SourceSystem
   FROM RequestDetail

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RequestData) as x,
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[1].Name') AS Name,
      JSON_VALUE(RequestData, '$[1].Value') AS SourceSystem
   FROM RequestDetail 
)x
GROUP BY x
;
```

This will give:

| x | SourceSystem | SourceSystemId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SSValue | XYZ |
| 2 | SSVALUE2 | SSID |

Comment: Your Answer is still selecting the values from the SourceSystemId element of the JSON--just like in my Question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, getting there. Now, if can, please, can I have the value of the SourceSystemId in your answer?? There will be many such values to be parsed. Thank you!!